# jquery fadein not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page loading into a div and I would like to to fade in so I tried to add it to the jquery function but it didn't work? Please help thank you !

```
<script>
function load(num){
   $("#gallery").load('home/page'+num+'.php').fadeIn('slow');

}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to do it in the callback function.

Comment: what is the call back function ?

Answer (score 9):

Use this:

```
$("#gallery").load('home/page'+num+'.php', function(){
    $("#gallery").fadeIn();
})
```

You may also need to add `display:none` to the element's CSS style.

Comment: it doesnt fade for some reason ?

Comment: Show me the element css style

Comment: #gallery {
 column-width: 320px;
 column-gap: 15px;
   width: 100%;
 max-width: 1100px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 padding-left: 70px;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

Comment: add display:none; property

Comment: i answered my question

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did...
This works

```
<script>
function load(num){
  $("#gallery").load('home/page'+num+'.php', function(){
    $("#gallery").css('display','none');
    $("#gallery").fadeIn('slow');
});

}
</script>
```